# System.InvalidOperationException:The contract name 'XYZInterfce' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'XYZWSImp'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, wcf, restful-url

I am trying Restful services. I am getting this error, what am I doing Wrong?? Please help
**Error:**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The contract name 'XYZ' could not be
>   found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'XYZWSImp'. 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupContract(String
>   contractName, String serviceName)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase
>   host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement,
>   Action`1 addBaseAddress, Boolean skipHost)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.LoadConfigurationSectionInternal(ConfigLoader
>   configLoader, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement
>   serviceSection)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection
>   baseAddresses)    at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.CreateServiceHost(Type type,
>   ServiceKind kind)    at
>   Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo
>   info)

**My interface Class:**

```
namespace XYZ
{
     [ServiceContract]
  interface XYZ_RestFullWSInterface
    {
         [OperationContract]
         [WebInvoke(
             Method = "GET",
             UriTemplate = "Encounter/{Identifier}",
             BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
             ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
         Encounter SearchEncounterByID(string Identifier);
```

**App.Cofig**

```
<pre><configuration>
...
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="XYZ.XYZWSImp">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="XYZ_RestFullWSInterface" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
</pre>
```

Comment: how you are using this interface to Service class.?Have implement this interface to Service class.?

Comment: did you try giving the fully qualified name (including the name space) for the contract attribute of the endpoint

Comment: Yes I have implemented this interface to Service class and given qualified name.

Comment: This is implementation Class:                                   namespace XYZ
{
   public class XYZWSImp:XYZ_RestFullWSInterface
    {
        public Encounter SearchEncounterByID(string Identifier)
        {
            
            EncounterByIDAdapter enounterByIdAdapter = new EncounterByIDAdapter();

            return   (Encounter)  enounterByIdAdapter.read(Identifier);

           
        }

Answer (score 1):

Try this.You are not passing fully qualified name in contract attribute

```
<services>
      <service name="XYZ.XYZWSImp">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="XYZ.XYZ_RestFullWSInterface" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

Comment: I tried this but now give this error---> InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].

Comment: check out this link http://rantdriven.com/post/2010/06/24/How-to-fix-Could-not-find-a-base-address-that-matches-scheme-http-for-the-endpoint-with-binding-WebHttpBinding-Errors.aspx